# Old Website URL Shows Up in Google for New Website

Tags: dns, web, google-search

I hosted a website quite a while back, let's call it abc.com. It's been shut down for quite some time, and recently I decided to build another website using the same IP and web server. This time, however, whenever I search for the new website on Google, it shows up as my old domain name.

So, it'll have abc.com, but with all my current website's information. I can even access the abc.com address directly, even though I'm not running the DNS for it anymore and there's no mention of it anywhere on my webserver. I completely wiped it.

As a note, I was using Cloudflare, does that have anything to do with it? How is this possible and does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: What exactly you had done to shutdown your old website?

Comment: Wiped the entire web server, clean reinstall of Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Than looks like most probably cloudflare is serving the cached version of it. Did you try to stop the current website and see if the webpage is still working?